# Can I create an AND and OR filter and apply that to a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, filters, business-logic

I'd like to create a Data Filter that has AND and OR conditions in it, like

`x AND y AND (a OR b OR c)`

I'm unable to merge two filters. Is this feasible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very feasible. You would just need to create child nesting conditions inside your drag and drop filter settings. See below screen shot for example:

[image]

To do this, you click on the little grey boxes at the end (highlighted part in image). This will create a 'nested conditional' inside of your overarching conditions.